# Upper bound on higher moments of the mean of iid random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, expectation

Given is a random sample $iid$ and zero mean random variable $X_i$ for which all moments are assumed to exist.

I am interested in a bound on the the higher moments of the mean of $X_1^2$, i.e. of 
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2.$$
To be specific, I want to show that for all $p\geq 1$ I have: 
\begin{align*}
E((\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2)^p)<\infty.
\end{align*}
Is this trivially implied since all moments of $X_i$ exists?

Note that as $n\to \infty$,  $(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2)^p$ converges almost surely to $Var(X_i)^p$, Hence I would guess, that 
$$E((\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2)^p) = Var(X_i)^p + o(1)$$
This asymptotic result would be sufficient, in order to derive it one needs uniform integrability of $(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2)^p$. I am not sure how to check it, or which conditions I need to state in order to derive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\mathsf{E}\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right]^p\le \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathsf{E}|X_i|^{2p}.
$$

Comment: I can not follow. dare to give some more details? which inequality did you use?

Comment: For $p>1$,
$$
\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\right|^p\le \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n|Y_i|^{p}.
$$

Comment: does it have a name or a reference? i searched (almost) everywhere for such an inequality.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form